# undefined method 'to_model' when linking thumbnail to original image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, carrierwave, link-to

I'm creating an album that I'm planning to display with Masonry and [ImgZoom](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgzoom/) so that the visitors can have a bigger image when they click on it.

According to ImgZoom, to make the zoom work, you need to do the following:

```
<a href="path/to/real/image.png">
    <img src="path/to/image's/thumbnail.png class="thumbnail" />
</a>
```

So I generated an uploader, with the following inside it:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    'portfolio/photos'
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [220, nil]
  end
end
```

Everything works perfectly, I can call both the versions without trouble, but when I try to follow ImgZoom's instructions by doing the following:

```
<%= @portfolio.photos.each do |p| %> 
#This is a nested form inside the portfolio form, so I need to do this to get my images

<%= link_to image_tag p.image.thumb.url, p.image %>
```

or:

```
<%= link_to p.image do %>
    <%= image_tag p.image.thumb.url, :class => 'thumbnail' %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the following error: `undefined method 'to_model' for #<ImageUploader:0x0000000c35f4d8>`

I found a similar subject on stack overflow but the asker wasn't clear and was invited to ask an other question on the forum, which I couldn't find.
I can individually reach 'p.image' and 'p.image.thumb.url', but I can't make a link from one to another, which would be perfectly doable with simple html.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried `<%= link_to p.image.url do %>`.... ?

Comment: This. This was THIS simple. Damnit! Could you please make this a real answer so I can accept it? Thank you a lot!

Comment: you can accept Simon's answer. I'm glad to be of help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to create the class "thumbnail" in the link, you need to declare it properly. I edited the link:

```
<%= link_to p.image.url do %>
    <%= image_tag p.image.url, class: "thumbnail" %>
<% end %>
```

Second, you need to check if you created an appropriate route for viewing the image. This can be either done by linking to a static assets properly (as your image is not under "public") or via a template view.

If the files where stored under "public", your way of linking should work just fine.

Check out how image_path works in the docs: [image_path (and more)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I'm positive about reaching the image, and their location inside "public", however, I tried your code and I still get the same error (sorry about forgetting the thumbnail class, i retyped the code for the question)

Comment: you are linking to p.image which does not result in a proper route. Meaning this image is not bound to a view, that is why the error is thrown. You could try 
`<%= link_to image_tag(p.image.url) do %>`

does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, the correct was to link p.image.url instead of p.image